# Flutter - Draw Graphs on the screen

Tags: graph, dart, drawing, flutter

Is there any library for Flutter (Dart) for drawing Graphs on the screen with a coordinate system?
Or how would I approach doing it from scratch?

Comment: Did you have a look at this blog post? https://medium.com/dartlang/zero-to-one-with-flutter-43b13fd7b354 I don't know if there are any high level libraries yet to draw graphs, but I think this would be how you do it from scratch.

Comment: Thank you, I'm definately going to take a look at it!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

<s>There is no graph drawing library for Flutter right now.</s> The Dart UI package contains a [canvas implementation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas-class.html). There are some examples using the class: example [mentioned in comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43703802/flutter-draw-graphs-on-the-screen#comment74452439_43703802), [part two in the series of those blog post](https://medium.com/dartlang/zero-to-one-with-flutter-part-two-5aa2f06655cb), or [this official example in the Flutter repo](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/layers/raw/canvas.dart). The official canvas example seems outdated, not all objects are rendered within the visible part of the canvas.

Flutter issues: There is an open issue for [Charting library for Flutter #9043](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9043), and a documentation issue [mentions questions regarding charting](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/3339) as well. Based on that information it doesn't seem like the Flutter team is currently working on charting components, so it could be done as a community effort.

**Update:** There is now a an open source Flutter library for charting created by Google called [chart_flutter](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/charts_flutter). Among the examples there is a [simple line chart example](https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/line_charts/simple) which might fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for clerifying, I guess I have something to do now... :)